# performance paradox: stack versus heap allocation (C++)

Tags: c++, performance, heap-memory, stack-memory

I was conducting some performance tests yesterday to see how big the difference between stack & heap allocation would be in practice.
What one would expect from such a test is that heap allocation is slightly slower or on par with stack allocation.
However, I was stunned to discover the opposite. I cannot explain why, and how it's even logically possible, but heap allocation is always slightly faster (i was compiling with optimizations OFF).

This is an example output:

```
ticks (stack): 42698
ticks (stack): 43977
ticks (stack): 44024
ticks (stack): 44070
ticks (stack): 45038

ticks (heap): 42588
ticks (heap): 43525
ticks (heap): 43633
ticks (heap): 43681
ticks (heap): 43071
```

It's a small difference but it's very consistent, it reproduces 100% of the time in favor of heap allocation.

Can anyone explain why do I get these strange results?

This is the code that i ran:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <windows.h>

using namespace std;

struct JJ
{
    int c[50];
    JJ(int i) { c[5] = 3; c[29] = 4; c[30] = i; c[49] = c[5]; }
};

void fill_direct_stack()
{
    vector<JJ> vec;
    for (int i=0; i<1000; ++i)
        vec.push_back(i);
}

void fill_direct_heap()
{
    vector<JJ>* pVec = new vector<JJ>();
    for (int i=0; i<1000; ++i)
        pVec->push_back(i);
    delete pVec;
}

CRITICAL_SECTION cs_print;

void print(string msg, DWORD val)
{
    EnterCriticalSection(&cs_print);
    cout << msg << val << endl;
    LeaveCriticalSection(&cs_print);
}

DWORD __stdcall threadEntry(void*)
{
    DWORD ticks1,ticks2;

    ticks1 = GetTickCount();
    for (int i=0; i<10000; ++i)
        fill_direct_stack();
    ticks2 = GetTickCount();
    print("ticks (stack): ", ticks2 - ticks1);

    ticks1 = GetTickCount();
    for (int i=0; i<10000; ++i)
        fill_direct_heap();
    ticks2 = GetTickCount();
    print("ticks (heap): ", ticks2 - ticks1);

    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    cout<<"hi"<<endl;

    InitializeCriticalSection(&cs_print);

#define N_THREADS 5

    HANDLE thr[N_THREADS];
    for (int i=0; i<N_THREADS; ++i)
        thr[i] = CreateThread(NULL, 0, &threadEntry, NULL, 0, NULL);

    for (int i=0; i<N_THREADS; ++i)
        WaitForSingleObject(thr[i], INFINITE);

    DeleteCriticalSection(&cs_print);

    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: This is meaningless. `vector` does heap allocation itself. The only things that go on the stack are a bunch of pointers.

Comment: This is a beautiful showcase of why a microbenchmark is utterly useless unless it carefully controls for confounding factors and does a proper statistical significance test. What you find is random noise. There is no consistency in the results, the supposed consistency results either from random sampling or other confounding factors.

Comment: Don't know why people downmodded this excellent question. I get the same  issue on a similar problem. And David Schwartz' answer - while I can't be sure is right - is definitely very insightful.

Answer (score 6):

The allocations

```
vector<JJ>* pVec = new vector<JJ>();
```

and

```
vector<JJ> vec;
```

are **nothing** compared to the push-backs and the internal memory management that `vector` does.

Comment: Though vector::push_back() doubles the capacity each time it needs to increase it, so you have only 9-10 allocations instead of 1000.

Comment: @satuon plus deletes, plus copying the data over...

Comment: I know the actual *data* of the vector is always stored on the heap, and that only its internal pointers are allocated on the stack (in the stack case), but even so, going through the heap manager to allocate the small overhead of the vector does take some CPU cycles compared to allocating on the stack which is one cycle.

Comment: @BogdanIonita but that is not all the code does, is it? (hint: since the answer is "no", that means you are wondering why those apples are less orange than these oranges over here)

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes I don't understand your question.

Comment: @BogdanIonita: The point is that this difference is miniscule, virtually microscopic. It would be dwarfed by *any* other difference. (For example, which will result in a higher data cache hit rate? Which will have more false sharing? These differences are also small, but they're not microscopic.)

Comment: @BogdanIonita both functions do more than creating a vector. Come on, you should know that, you wrote it.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes correct, but they do the same thing, so no difference can come from that part.

Comment: That is what everyone is trying to tell you: difference *can* come from that part (and there are also some stats involved).

Comment: @BogdanIonita if you want to test the performance of stack vs heap, why not just test that and get rid of all other code?

Comment: @LuchianGrigore Good point, I tried that now, and the outcome is as expected, with heap being slower. The initial benchmark was derived from some different code that i used to test how these two cases perform overall in a real life use case, versus a memory-pool, but i extracted only this part because I noticed the initial strange behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to say what accounts for such a slight difference in such an artificial benchmark. But my guess would be that it's an alignment issue. If you allocate from the heap, you get a chunk of memory suitably aligned for storing any type. If you allocate from the stack, you get a chunk of memory only minimally aligned, suitable for the type you are storing.

My other theory is that it's the data cache hit rate. Consider one thread finishing and then another thread running on the same core. With a stack allocation, the allocations will never be to the same chunk of memory since each thread has its own stack. The data cache will be cold. With a heap allocation, the allocation will likely get the same block just freed by the previous thread. The chunk of memory will be hot in the CPU data cache. (This theory would predict quite a bit of variation in the numbers though -- I think more than you're seeing.)

But the difference is so small, it could be anything.

Comment: interesting answer, this could be a possible explanation